# Mysql sync on Work and Home computers

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have two Windows 7 systems located in two different locations - work and home, with XAMPP running on both of them. I would like to be able to sync the mysql databases located on the machines. The problem is that both the machines do not stay connnected to the internet continously and do not have dedicated IPs.

I thought of using some cloud hosting service to share the "data" folder in mysql. But for some reason, the tables for the db are not showing up in System #2, thought it said DB(3) - 3 being the number of tables in the database. In this case, i didn't sync the whole of data folder, but the folder of a particular database. Not sure if this is a way of doing it.

Is there a better method of syncing both the databases. Please note that I only work on both the machines and update the database only in one location at a time. So the issue of conflicting records won't occur. I just would like both the systems updated with the same data at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how big your DB is but you could just use an external hard drive as your MySQL path.

Comment: I don't want to use external hard disk. I just want to be able to sync it online.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DB's sizes probably [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/) can be a solution because it mirrors a local directory which may serve as your MySQL data path to their cloud. Although using it for all kinds of snychronisation (including Smalltalk images) I never tried using it as a DB data directory.

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried syncing a db folder in data... But only the database name is appearing on the other machine and not the tables.